# What is the dialogflowURL when connecting Angular, Nebular, and Dialogflow?

Tags: angular, firebase, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NXqwT3Y09E&t=499s&ab_channel=Fireship), which is a nice start, but leaves out a lot of details about the implementation.

Line 4 of the component typescript file is the following:

```
const dialogflowURL = 'https://us-central1-fireship-lessons.cloudfunctions.net/dialogflowGateway';
```

For my project id, `yalebot-n9xq`, I think the accurate URL is:

```
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/yalebot-n9xq/dialogflowGateway
```

However, `curl https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/yalebot-n9xq/dialogflowGateway` gives a 404 response:

```
<p>The requested URL <code>/v2/projects/yalebot-n9xq/dialogflowGateway</code> was not found on this server.  
<ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

**What URL should I be using if my project id is yalebot-n9xq?**

1. I have enabled the webhook for the welcome intent.
2. If I don't use angular and serve locally `(curl http://localhost:5000/yalebot-n9xq/us-central1/dialogflowGateway`), I have the desired response from dialogflow.
3. `ng serve` yields `http://localhost:4200/`, but visiting that site or `/#` yields the error 'Cannot GET /', which is why I believe my error is in typing the correct URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that Dialoflow looks for an external webhook.

In [this example](https://fireship.io/lessons/build-a-chatbot-with-dialogflow/), `const dialogflowURL = 'https://YOUR-CLOUDFUNCTION/dialogflowGateway';` the `YOUR-CLOUDFUNCTION` refers to an external URL, perhaps something externalized with `ngrok` or `lite-server`.

The example works fine with an external URL that is cross-listed under the DialogFlow fulfillment tab.